# Trying to find the vm_list->vm_node struct definition in linux/include/linux/kvm_host.h

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel, kvm

I'm trying to find the struct definition for the struct vm_list in the KVM struct.  I've been grepping and navigating through http://code.woboq.org/ and I can't seem to find the definition of it.  Am I missing something as to why I can't find it's definition for it?  Below is a link to it in the KVM struct.

http://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/include/linux/kvm_host.h.html#376

I'm specifically looking for the members of the nodes that make up this linked list.  I've seen code that reference members of it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what you don't understand. Including a `struct list_head vm_list` in the "KVM struct" allows multiple "KVM structs" to be linked together in a list. `struct list_head` does not implement a list in itself, it's a "mixin" to add to any structure that you want to maintain a list of, that allows you to use a specific set of functions to help you maintain that list so you don't have to re-invent the doubly linked list for every structure...

Comment: @twalberg sorry for the confusion that was my question what are the nodes of the linked list which as you said are KVM structs.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the line of interest:

```
struct list_head vm_list;
```

`vm_list` is just the name of the variable in the kvm struct. `list_head` is the struct you want to find to see what a vm_list is made of. Hovering over it on the site you linked leads you to [linux/types.h](http://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/include/linux/types.h.html#list_head):

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};
```

Comment: thanks but I'm specifically looking for the members of the nodes that make up this linked list.  I should have been more specific and I updated my question.